# How to group by data using one column perform some operation on another column and assign new groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below :

```
   distance_along_path  ID
0       0                1
1       2.2              1
2       4.5              1
3       7.0              1
4       0                2
5       0                3
6       3.0              2
7       5.0              3
8       0                4
9       2.0              4
10      5.0              4
11      0                5
12      3.0              5 
11      7.0              4
12
```

I want be able to group these by id's first and the by distance_along_path values, every time a 0 is seen in distance along path for the id, new group is created and until the next 0 all these rows are under A group as indicated below

```
   distance_along_path  ID       group    
0       0                1        1
1       2.2              1        1 
2       4.5              1        1
3       7.0              1        1 
4       0                1        2
5       0                2        3
6       3.0              1        2
7       5.0              2        3
8       0                2        4
9       2.0              2        4
10      5.0              2        4
11      0                1        5 
12      3.0              1        5
13      7.0              1        5
14      0                1        6
15      0                2        7
16      3.0              1        6
17      5.0              2        7
18      1.0              2        7
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
grp_id = df.groupby(['ID']).id.count().reset_index()

grp_distance = grp_id.groupby(['distance_along_path'].grp_id['distance_along_path']==0
```